# How to redirect jpeg to jpg extensions with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code on my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.jpg$ 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.JPG -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.JPG [L]
```

Which I took from a post on how to redirect JPG to jpg images. Now I need to change all jpeg to jpg, because the gallery I'm using won't work otherwise. How can I do that without taking out the code above?

Comment: `....\.jpe?g`? `?` = "zero or one of the previous"

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't "redirect JPG to jpg", it _internally rewrites_ from jpg to JPG (which is the other way round). What format are the image filenames on the filesystem?

Comment: Thing is, I have .jpg and .JPG images, and in the code I dynamically generate a gallery with the .jpg extension so the ones with .JPG didn't work but with that code, the ones with .JPG worked and the ones with .jpg did also work.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpeg$ /$1.jpg [L,NC,R=301]`